# prevent IP POE cameras from congesting the LAN

Tags: ip-camera, dvr, power-over-ethernet

i am installing a 16 camera ip poe system.  the nvr comes with 8 ports and the system comes with a separate 8 port poe switch which needs to connect to the network and not directly to the nvr.

if i put a separate [simple layer 2 switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vintF.jpg) in front of the main switch with both the nvr and poe switch connected to it, will that prevent the camera traffic from the poe switch from getting to the main switch?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the only time information will pass from the NVR network to your main network is if someone is live streaming the cameras. Depending on the resolutions/frame rates/codec being used, 16 cams could very well hit your 100Mbps limit through that switch in the picture will  result in packet loss or you just wont be able to view some streams. The recordings should still be safe, though.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the implementation of the cameras. If all the cameras need is to send traffic to the nvr, then the shortest route is going to be from the camera to the separate switch to the NVR. Assuming this is the implemenation, you shouldn't see any congestion on the main network because of it.

However, if the cameras need to separately talk to the internet then the additional switch won't help.

Only way to really know is to test it out; or call the manufacturer!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but you'd still get all the broadcast chatter on the rest of your network.

If it was me, I would just buy a 24-port PoE switch and hook up all 16 cameras, the NVR, and your router/uplink to that.  Unmanaged switches are cheap nowadays.  Having four or more cheap switches in some unusual arrangement isn't recommended.